# Выбор одного значения из клетки

Tags: php, mysql

Как взять только одно значение из клетки у котороый всего 6 значений?

Мне надо взять значение каждой сотни в отдельную клетку в таблицу ниже

Заранее спасибо. :)

```
           $table .= "<tr>";
           $table .= "<td>Skill:</td>";
           $table .= "<td>".$row['pSkills']."</td>";
           $table .= "</tr>";
```

[image: Колонка mysql]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из представленного вами изображения (данные в столбце) у вас всегда будет шесть элементов (если больше, необходимо доп. условие для вывода). Вытаскиваем их из БД (думаю у вас это получилось), затем прогоняем функцией [explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php), а после выводите нужный элемент или прогоняете циклом.

Решение:

```
$str = '0,1,2,3,4,5';
$mas = explode(',',$str);

$table .= "<tr>";
$table .= "<td>Skill:</td>";
$table .= "<td>".$mas[0]."</td>";
$table .= "</tr>";
```

Или циклом:

```
foreach ($mas as $value) {
    $table .= "<tr>";
    $table .= "<td>Skill:</td>";
    $table .= "<td>".$value."</td>";
    $table .= "</tr>";
}
```

*P.S. Вместо `$str` вставьте `$row['pSkills']`.*

Comment: У меня получалось вытащить только целиком через
$table .= "<td>".$row['pSkills']."</td>";
Не подскажите как его вытащить оттуда?

Comment: @breddy мой ответ, является решением вашего вопроса?

Comment: Почти,у меня получилось вытащить только все 6 элементов,а как вытащить только один я не понял

Comment: @breddy подправил ответ)

Comment: ,Большое спасибо.

Comment: @breddy Успехов!